# SQL Query to Join Two Tables With The Following Output

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to write a simple query as a part of larger function to join two tables. The tables are as under

**Table1**

```
Code    Subactivity
647     1
647     2
648     3
648     4
```

**Table 2**

```
Subactivity    Hours
1              5
2              10
3              7
4              3
```

The final output should look like

```
Code    hours
647     15
648     10
```

I have done this before, but today I just cant get my head around it..

Comment: Please learn to use your shift key. SHOUTING DOESN'T HELP YOU GET ANSWERS FASTER, and it just makes your question harder to read (which is probably why they invented the shift key in the first place).

Comment: You gave me a negative score for that? I'll consider you advice from now on wards but you need to stop pressing the neg button just because you don't like all caps text.Also, I would understand if my description was all upper case but I think the questions is still pretty easy to read...

Comment: I didn't 'give a negative vote' here. I corrected your SHOUTING, but did not dowovote the question. Before you accuse someone of doing something, you should be sure you have the right person. (I probably should have downvoted, because you've shown no effort here to solve it yourself other than saying "I have done this before", but I didn't.)

Comment: My apologies, It's just that the your comment coincided with the negative score and I assumed that you did it. Also, thanks you for your input and I'll make sure that my questions here show more effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE([Code] INT,[Subactivity] INT)
INSERT INTO @t1 VALUES(647,1),(647,2),(648,3),(648,4)

DECLARE @t2 TABLE([Subactivity] INT, [Hours] INT)
INSERT INTO @t2 VALUES(1,5),(2,10),(3,7),(4,3)

SELECT t1.Code,SUM(t2.Hours) hours
FROM @t1 t1 JOIN @t2 t2 ON t1.subactivity = t2.subactivity
GROUP BY t1.CODE
```

**Result**

```
Code    hours
647      15
648      10
```

Comment: Yeah I have been trying to do that, since my score is pretty low i need to wait some time before I can accept an answer..